# mysql query with vertical display of results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a special case for retrieving data from a table. The table data is given below:

```
Col1  Col2
E1    N1
E2    N2
E1    N3
E3    N4
E1    N5
E3    N6
```

Now I need to display result in the following format:

```
E1  N1  N3 N5
E2  N2
E3  N4  N6
```

This is really a weird kind of case...any help on this is appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Not exaclty what you want but way easier to achieve

```
select co1, group_concat(col2 order by col2 separator ' ') as col2
from your_table
group by col1
```

Comment: this is exactly what i need only issue is when am printing it in php page the col2 separator value is not being displayed in a different column

Comment: Yes, I know. That is much harder to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

One relatively easy way to do this is using `group_concat()`.  However, you will only get two columns:

```
select col1, group_concat(col2 separator ' ')
from table t;
```